# Swift Firebase ordering query

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Disclaimer: I am very new to coding and Firebase.

My JSON tree looks like this :

```
      “MAIN LEAGUE“ : {
                “Team Alpha“ : {
                    "Team Score" : “50”,
                    "Total Time " : "02:22:05",
                    "Team Name" : “Team Alpha“,

                        },
                “Team Bravo“ : {
                    "Team Score" : “200”,
                    "Total Time" : "02:09:58",
                    "Team Name" : “Team Bravo“
                     },
                “Team Charlie“ : {
                    “Team Score“ : “150”,
                    "Total Time" : "02:16:50",
                    "Team Name" : “Team Charlie“
                        }
        }
```

I am trying to query the database and present a new tableview whereby the teams are ranked by highest "Team Score".

So trying to show, in this order :

```
" Team Bravo" : "200"
" Team Charlie" : "150"
" Team Alpha" : "50"
```

I'm a bit lost. I have tried, to no avail (the below returns nothing in the tableview):

```
  struct content {
        var sTitle : String!
        var sValue : Any!

        init(sTitle: String, sValue: Any) {
            self.sTitle = sTitle
            self.sValue = sValue
        }
    }

    var dbHandleQuery: FIRDatabaseHandle?

    var dbrefString = (myDatabasePath)// this is the database path to the correct child 
     ("MAIN LEAGUE")

          dbHandleQuery=FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(dbrefString).queryOrdered(byChild: "Team Score").observe( .value, with: {(snapshot) in

   var newContent : [content] = []
            for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                let title = snap.key as String
                let message = snap.value as? String
                print(snap.key)
                print(snap.value as Any)
                newContent.append(content(sTitle: title, sValue: message as Any))
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
            self.cellContent = newContent
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        })
```

How could I achieve that ranking? Or would it be better to try load everything in local arrays and then try rank them from there? Any help, greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: So the above does rank them correctly, but my table only retrieves the TEAM NAME, and I cannot extract the "Total Score" to put inside my tableview cell 2nd Label (it has 2 labels, 1 for Team Name, 1 for Total Score).

So now it looks like this :

```
" Team Bravo"
" Team Charlie"
" Team Alpha"
```

How can I attach each corresponding Total Score next to each one? Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok not sure this is the best possible answer, but I managed to make it work and get the result I wanted.

Posting it to help anyone who might run into the same issue:

```
    dbHandleQuery = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(dbrefString).queryOrdered(byChild: "Team Score").observe( .value, with: {(snapshot) in
        var counter = 0
        var newContent : [content] = []
        for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            counter += 1
            let title = snap.key as String
            if let rankedBy = snap.value as? [String : Any]  {

            newContent.append(content(sTitle: "\(counter).\(title)", sValue: rankedBy["Team Score"] as Any))
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        self.cellContent = newContent
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    })
```

This gives me

```
"1.Team Bravo" - "200"
"2.Team Charlie" - "150"
"3.Team Alpha" - "50"
```

Comment: Make sure you index your database on "Team Score" if you are going to use this code. There is an example in the Firebase documentation that extremely similar to your code here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data